# ggplot sorting a bar graph when reorder is not possible

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a dataframe which has only 2 columns, var and fill (both factors). I create a bar graph from this using

```
ggplot(df, aes(var, fill=fill)) + geom_bar()
```

The reason I am doing this is because I need a stacked histogram. The y values which are the counts of various values in var seem to be implicitly calculated by ggplot. All this is perfectly fine.

Now, my problem is the resulting graph is not sorted and I cannot sort this using the usual method of reordering since there is no explicit y value here.

How do I do this?

EDIT : Sample Data and plot (I want the plot to be sorted so I see NA first, SA next and Europe last)

```
> df = data.frame(var=c("NA","EU","SA","NA","SA","NA"),fill=c("f1","f2","f2","f1","f2","f2"))
> df
  var fill
1  NA   f1
2  EU   f2
3  SA   f2
4  NA   f1
5  SA   f2
6  NA   f2
> ggplot(df, aes(x=var, fill=fill)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample data, if you can?

Comment: Edited my question with sample data and plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create ordered factor to do that. In the `levels` argument you can change the order as you like. When you write `ordered = TRUE` it will preserve the order

```
df$var <- factor(df$var,levels = c("SA","NA","EU"),ordered = TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x=var, fill=fill)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Still puts NA in the middle though. I want NA at the start, SA next and EU last.

Comment: in the first line of code in levels argument change the order like `levels = c("NA","SA","EU")` you can play with the order